# I was trying to configure hermes for ActiveMQ. When I am trying to add a queue, I am getting error

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, soapui

After doing all the mentioned steps on the "Getting Started | JMS" page on SoapUI website http://www.soapui.org/JMS/getting-started.html . When I am trying to add a queue, I am getting error.

The error is:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.activemq.util.IdGenerator
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.getClientIdGenerator(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:969)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:363)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:331)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:303)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:243)
    at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionManagerSupport.createConnection(ConnectionManagerSupport.java:122)
    at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionManagerSupport.createConnection(ConnectionManagerSupport.java:92)
    at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionSharedManager.reconnect(ConnectionSharedManager.java:81)
    at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionSharedManager.connect(ConnectionSharedManager.java:91)
    at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionSharedManager.getConnection(ConnectionSharedManager.java:104)
    at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionSharedManager.getObject(ConnectionSharedManager.java:142)
    at hermes.impl.jms.ThreadLocalSessionManager.connect(ThreadLocalSessionManager.java:190)
    at hermes.impl.jms.ThreadLocalSessionManager.getSession(ThreadLocalSessionManager.java:570)
    at hermes.impl.jms.AbstractSessionManager.getDestination(AbstractSessionManager.java:460)
    at hermes.impl.DefaultHermesImpl.getDestination(DefaultHermesImpl.java:367)
    at hermes.browser.tasks.EditDestinationPropertiesTask.invoke(EditDestinationPropertiesTask.java:80)
    at hermes.browser.tasks.TaskSupport.run(TaskSupport.java:175)
    at hermes.browser.tasks.ThreadPool.run(ThreadPool.java:170)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

The hermes ver. 1.14 & activemq ver. 5.10.0 .

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you are missing some jar on the classpath.

Have you read the [official docs](http://activemq.apache.org/hermes-jms.html)?

These jars should contains all classes:

- activemq-all.jar
- geronimo-j2ee-management_1.0_spec-1.0.jar

(activemq-client.jar might do, not sure).